# ParametricPlot3D for only part of a sphere

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

I want to plot the region of a sphere that satisfies the equation

$$
\tan\theta\geq-\frac{rz}{rx\cos\phi + ry\sin\phi}
$$

where $rx$, $ry$, $rz$ are known constants. The spherical coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$ are linked together, making the desired region a smooth cutout of the total sphere.

The basic parametric plot code for a sphere is:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}]
```

I essentially want to apply the above inequality to the limits of this plot, but cannot figure out how to successfully do so. I could just create a table of points in this region and use `ListPlot3D` or something, but I would prefer a smooth surface.

Comment: Try `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{\[Phi], \[Theta]}, 
  Tan[\[Theta]] >= -z/(x Cos[\[Phi]] + y Sin[\[Phi]])]`

Comment: That `RegionFunction` will not work because it includes variables $x$, $y$, and $z$ along with $\theta$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Actually this works perfectly! x,y,z are known constants. I had just never heard of RegionFunction before.

Comment: OP said they are values that are specified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try also using `Boole`. As it was commented by Jason B it requires a certain values of the `PlotPoints` and `PlotRange`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
   Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}*
  Boole[Tan[θ] + 1/(Cos[ϕ] + Sin[ϕ]) > 0], {ϕ, 
  0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

where I put `x=y=z=1`. It gives this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: I was also thinking that using `Boole` was the simplest way to solve this.  But you have to increase the `PlotPoints` and specify the `PlotRange`.  If you add `, PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> Full` as options it makes the plot perfect.

Comment: @Jason B You are right. I will edit the answer.

Comment: You could even make it a function of x, y, and z so that it works for any values..

Comment: @Jason B Of course, I was simply lazy today.

Answer (score 8):

The way I understood the question, the Cartesian parameters are fixed. I'm just going to call them $x_0$, $y_0$ and $z_0$. But since in spherical coordinates we also have $x=r\cos\phi \sin\theta$, $y=r\sin\phi\sin\theta$, $z=r\cos\theta$, we can rewrite the inequality as

$$0 \le x_0 x + y_0 y + z_0 z $$

(the radial coordinate $r$ cancels). This leads me to the following implementation using `MeshFunctions`:

```
With[{x0 = -1/2, y0 = 0, z0 = 1/2},
 SphericalPlot3D[1, θ, ϕ, Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotPoints -> 70,
   MeshShading -> {None, Orange},
  MeshStyle -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, x x0 + y y0 + z z0]}]]
```

[image: sphere]

I used `SphericalPlot3D` because it's fast. The mesh only has the contour `0` because that's the cutoff for the inequality. The formulation of the problem now uses only Cartesian coordinates, so I need just the corresponding first three arguments of the mesh function.

However, in multiplying the original inequality by trig functions to bring it into the simpler form above, some sign changes are lost. Thanks to theDude for pointing that out. The original inequality can easily be plotted in the same way, though:

```
With[{x0 = -1/2, y0 = 0, z0 = 1/2}, 
 SphericalPlot3D[1, θ, ϕ, Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotPoints -> 70,
   MeshShading -> {None, Orange}, MeshStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
     Tan[θ] + z0 /(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ])]}]]
```

[image: plot2]

The plot agrees with the result of thedude's answer, but this method is faster.

Comment: Your conversion neglects the signs. MeshFunction should be Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, 
 Tan[θ] + z0/(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ])]

Comment: @thedude Indeed, I think you're right. I'll change it.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach:

```
x0 = -1; y0 = 0; z0 = 1;
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}}];
reg2 = ImplicitRegion[
          Reduce[TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", 
             Tan[θ] >= -z0/(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ]), {r, θ, ϕ} -> {x, y, z}] && 
             x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && z ∈ Reals &&
            -1 < x < 1 && -1 < y < 1 && -1 < z < 1, {x, y, z}
          ] // Quiet,
          {x, y, z}
       ];

DiscretizeRegion[RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2], MaxCellMeasure -> 10^-4]
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Apparently what OP wants is

```
With[
 {x0 = -1/2, y0 = 0, z0 = 1/2},
 ParametricPlot3D[
  {Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ]*Sin[θ], 
   Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π}, 
  RegionFunction -> 
   Function[{ϕ, θ}, 
    Tan[θ] + z0/(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ]) >= 0], 
  PlotRange -> All
  ]
 ]
```

However, I cannot tell why the output doesn't agree with my and Jens's answer. Does anyone have an explanation?

---

**EDIT 2**

Jens's plot yields:

[image]

if `MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, θ, ϕ, r}, Tan[θ] + z0 /(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ])]}` is replaced with  `MeshFunctions -> {Function[{θ, ϕ, r}, Tan[θ] + z0 /(x0 Cos[ϕ] + y0 Sin[ϕ])]}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot3D[
  If[Tan[θ] + -Cos[ϕ]/(
     Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ] Cos[ϕ] + 
      Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] Sin[ϕ]) > 
    0, {Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], 
    Cos[θ]}, Null],
  {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
  PlotPoints -> 200] // Quiet
```

[image]

or

```
ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{θ, ϕ}, 
    Tan[θ] + -Cos[ϕ]/(Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ] Cos[ϕ] + Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ] Sin[ϕ]) > 0],
  PlotPoints -> 100] // Quiet
```